# "My Tasks" filter does not display new tasks

Tags: designer-workflow, tasks, task-list, approval-process

I used the "My Tasks" filter which comes with the OOTB Task list. It shows older tasks which were created a few days ago, but in order to see the "new" tasks created within the past hour, I have to go to the "All Tasks" view and filter on my name. The only filter I have is "Assigned to = [Me]", so I'm not sure why it's excluding the others.

update: I checked the two items of mine which fail to show in the correct view, and they are somehow pointing to my name without the middle initial shown in my usual display name. Also, even though I receive the alert/email and can edit the task.. it doesn't count the account as my own. I have concatenated the list of approvers by email based on some fields I pick up (e.g., If price > 9999, approverstring = approverstring;[someHighLevelApprover]). I store all of those by email. Maybe I should switch them to user ID concatenations instead.

Comment: what your problem is? You have filter on the list assigned to = me but you cannt see the all task for others as well?

Comment: No, I cannot see my OWN new items. 4 items have my name on it. 2 Show on the view.

Comment: is their any workflow or approval process attached to the list? also try to create another view with the same filter...chances are may be view corrupted?

Comment: I tried that. The issue is that my email address is somehow linked to two accounts as far as SharePoint is concerned (one with my middle initial and another without it). The view only shows the one with my middle initial. I am attempting a solution now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that my email address was somehow not unique enough in SharePoint even though it should only point to one person (me).

I changed my user `approverstring` concatenation to split users up with "Login names, semi-colon delimited" and changed the approval to "`Start with [approverstring] as String`"